# Is there a lazyloader function for creating images in Coldfusion8?

Tags: image, coldfusion, lazy-loading

I have a product search displaying thumbnails and also offering a zoom view of the current result set (1-24 results).

In Coldfusion I'm currently doing this to create lo-res and hi-res images:

```
<cfimage name="myImage" source="#bildpfad##bilddateiname#" action="read" />
    <cfif IsImage(myImage) is true>
    <cfscript>
        variables.breakdown = "";
        variables.lastcount = 0;
    </cfscript> 
    <!--- low res --->
    <cfscript>
        ImageSetAntialiasing(myImage,"on");
        variables.breite = ImageGetWidth(myImage);
        variables.breite = 240;
        ImageScaleToFit(myImage, variables.breite,"");
    </cfscript>
    <cfxml variable="imageXml">
        <cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#myImage#" />
    </cfxml>
    <cfset variables.imageSrc = imageXml.xmlRoot.xmlAttributes.src>
    <!--- hi res --->
    <cfscript>
        variables.breite = 900;
        ImageScaleToFit(myImage, variables.breite,"");
    </cfscript>
    <cfxml variable="imageXmlXL">
        <cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#myImage#"/>
    </cfxml>
    <cfset variables.imageSrcXL = imageXmlXL.xmlRoot.xmlAttributes.src>
    <cfoutput><div class="resultsImgWrap">
        <a href="#variables.imageSrcXL#">#imageXml#</a></div>
    </cfoutput>
```

While this works nicely in creating thumbnails and zoom images simultaneously, it takes a while to process...

So I'm wondering if there is something like a lazy-loader function in Coldfusion, which would display the thumbnails right away and create the zoom images "in the background".

**Question:**
Any idea if something like this is possible? Or if there is a better way, I also wouldn't mind.

Thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can resize once (like right after the image is uploaded/added) and always use that thumbnail.  This would be my choice.

As for lazy loading... You'll need some sort of JavaScript plugin that does ajax image loading.  Each img src can be something like `getThumnail.cfm?id=x&w=200&h=200`.  You can also cache the resized thumbnail on the CF side.

Comment: Most images though are on external servers (clients) and pulled in when the search loads, so I need to do this on runtime. Otherwise your solution sounds good.

Comment: Henry - you don't want to resize "on the fly" constantly - cfimage is an expensive tag as is all version of Java Image processing. Once the image is resized you should store as a thumb file and re-use it from disk. that's my take :)